# Change image source in code behind - Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, imagesource

I need to set image source dynamically, please note my image is in somewhere on the Network, here is my code

```
BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
logo.BeginInit();
logo.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,\\myserver\\folder1\\Customer Data\\sample.png");
logo.EndInit(); // Getting the exception here
ImageViewer1.Source = logo;
```

Exception:

> The URI prefix is not recognized

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You just need one line:

```
ImageViewer1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\myserver\folder1\Customer Data\sample.png"));
```

Answer (score 82):

None of the above solutions worked for me.  But this did:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/foo.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: +1 for being so recent. Also it's the only thing that worked for me too.

Comment: Note that this _doesn't_ work in UWP, because UWP seems to only accept Absolute URIs.  Here's how I do it:  `myImage.Source = new BitmapImage (new Uri (new Uri (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), UriKind.Absolute), new Uri (@"/Images/foo.png", UriKind.Relative)));`

Comment: This probably doesn't answer the question, but since my question brought me here, this answer worked for me.

Comment: The only problem I experience with this, is that the transparency of the png is lost, and there seems to be no way, to restore it...

Comment: Note That this and @Thought answer's doesn't work in WinUI 3. Because `GetCurrentDirectory()` return `system32 ` directory. Instead You have to use this : `loginLogo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, UriKind.Absolute), new Uri(@"Assets\Images\logo-adaptive-white.png", UriKind.Relative)));`

Answer (score 5):

The pack syntax you are using here is for an image that is contained as a Resource within your application, not for a loose file in the file system.

You simply want to pass the actual path to the UriSource:

```
logo.UriSource = new Uri(@"\\myserver\folder1\Customer Data\sample.png");
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the methods worked for me as i needed to pull the image from a folder instead of adding it to the application.
The below code worked:

```
TestImage.Source = GetImage("/Content/Images/test.png")

private static BitmapImage GetImage(string imageUri)
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("pack://siteoforigin:,,,/" + imageUri,             UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My NET 7 project file looks as follows.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="images\RuntimePicture.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="images\RuntimePicture.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Resource>
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

As the proj file indicates, I have an image in a folder called images.
The code behind ctor looks as follows.

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ImageEx.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/images/RuntimePicture.png", UriKind.Relative));

}
```

The main window xaml for image would be as follows.

```xml
<Image x:Name="ImageEx" Height="300" Width="500" />
```

Finally right click the png file and in the file properties window, ensure **Build Action** is set to **Resource**.

Answer (score -4):

You are all wrong!
Why? Because all you need is this code to work:

(image View) / C# Img is : your Image box

Keep this as is, without change ("ms-appx:///) this is code not your app name
Images is your folder in your project you can change it.
dog.png is your file in your folder, as well as i do my folder 'Images' and file 'dog.png'
So the uri is :"ms-appx:///Images/dog.png"
and my code :

---

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/dog.png"));
    }
```

Comment: I'd say you're all wrong because none of you provided a complete working example.  It's just assumed that the reader knows where in the code to place these snippets.

Comment: Flippant remarks at the start of an answer are unnecessary. Full working answers, with directions on how to use are all that's required.