# Crash on changing the Image source property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, crash

```
<Image x:Name="pageImg" Margin="-19,-1,37,19" Source="/img/1.png" Stretch="Uniform"  />
```

The images property also set to `Build Action = Resource` and Copy `Output Directory = Cope if newer`

When the button get clicked the application crashes:

```
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            pageImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/img/2.png"));
        }
```

But when I pass `C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\2.png` instead of `/img/2.png` it works just fine.

Why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change image source in code behind - Wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787137/change-image-source-in-code-behind-wpf)

Comment: @J.H. Thanks it worked nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem :

```
pageImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/img/2.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 2):

An image resource file (with `Build Action` set to `Resource`) should be loaded by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly):

```
pageImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/img/2.png"));
```

It is not necessary to get it copied to the output directory.